# Fetching file from db and save it into local folder using python

Tags: python, database, zip, blob, cx-oracle

I am trying to retrieve data from database and save it into excel/csv file, There is column containing blob data , i have to save that data in .zip format in a local folder with name of that file (i.e., the name of the file containing that blob data, which is already a column value in my database).
I have written the below code to store all the non blob column in my excel but i am not able to fetch that blob column from db and save it into the folder. Please suggest.

```
import os
import cx_Oracle
import csv

SQL="SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE"


filename="S:\Output.csv"
FILE=open(filename,"w");
output=csv.writer(FILE, dialect='excel')



connection = cx_Oracle.connect('userid/password@99.999.9.99:PORT/SID')

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(SQL)
for row in cursor:
    output.writerow(row)
cursor.close()
connection.close()
FILE.close()
```

Thanks,
Aditya Singh

Comment: Just curious... why are you doing it with Python and not directly from the db?

Comment: @Swagga I m trying to automate  a manual process.

Comment: @Maurice , i don't think fetch all will solve my problem

Comment: it might still make more sense to just use cron via command line because writing line by line is not efficient..

Comment: If each row of data is a file that needs to added to a single zip, look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html  Also check the cx_Oracle doc for LOB tips: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/lob_data.html

Comment: @Christopher I want each row as individual zip file.