# Reading blob data from database by python and store it in .zip format

Tags: python, oracle, blob, cx-oracle

Hi I am trying to store blob data from my oracle database using python and trying to store it in a local folder in .zip format. So i have two codes now one of which is running fine but fetching only one row and storing it as .zip in a folder, but the other one in which i am trying to fetch multiple row , not working , Probably i am doing some basic mistake, but not able to figure out , so please help me . Below are the codes:-

code 1-running fine and fetching only one row and storing it as .zip in a folder:-

```
import cx_Oracle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
con = cx_Oracle.connect("OPTDB90", "OPTDB90", "INDLIN2338:1521/OPTEPC1")
cursor = con.cursor()
sql_string = """SELECT F_name, F_released_data FROM epc_project where rownum<5"""
cursor.execute(sql_string)
#Path="C:\Users\adityasi\Desktop\MY Important\QueryGeneratorPytthonFinal\Project\EPCPROJECTS"
row = cursor.fetchone()
blobdata = np.array(row[1].read())
cursor.close()
filename = str(row[0]) + ".zip"
f = open(filename, 'w+b')
binary_format = bytearray(blobdata)
f.write(binary_format)
f.close()
```

code 2-Throwing error and unable to fetch multiple row and storing it as .zip in a folder:-

```
import cx_Oracle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
con = cx_Oracle.connect("OPT", "OPT", "INDLIN2338:1521/OPT1")
cursor = con.cursor()
sql_string = """SELECT F_name, F_released_data FROM epc_project where rownum<5"""
cursor.execute(sql_string)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
        blobdata= np.array(row[1].read())
        cursor.close()
        filename =str(row[0]) + ".zip"
con.close()
f = open(filename, "wb")
binary_format = bytearray(blobdata)
f.write(binary_format)
f.close()
```

Error:-

```
     blobdata= np.array(row[1].read())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please help me out here.
Thanks,
Aditya

Comment: It may have been better to continue your question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58841272/fetching-file-from-db-and-save-it-into-local-folder-using-python  Also you don't show your problem code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the use of numpy is needed or not but you have a couple of options at your disposal in any case:

(1) use an output type handler to ensure that the LOB data is returned as bytes directly instead of as a BLOB on which you must call read(). See the [documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/lob_data.html#fetching-lobs-as-strings-and-bytes) for details on how to do that.

(2) iterate over the cursor and process each row separately, as in:

```
cursor.execute(sql_string)
for name, data in cursor:
    create_zip_file()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. i have tried to iterate over the cursor. But getting error , Please see the updated Problem statement.

Comment: That error implies that the column is already being returned as a string, so no need to call read() on it!

Answer (score -1):

try this one )

```py
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql_string = 'select id, photo from NEO_V '
row = cursor.execute(sql_string)
img_name, img_file = cursor.fetchone()
path = 'C:\\ii\\bever_31_005\\dataset\\'
mask = ".jpg"
for rows in row:
    #blobdata= np.array(row[1].read())
    filename = f'{path}{str(rows[0])}{mask}'
    #print (filename)
    offset = 1
    num_bytes_in_chunk = 65536
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        while True:
            data = rows[1].read(offset, num_bytes_in_chunk)
            if data:
                f.write(data)
            if len(data) < num_bytes_in_chunk:
                break
            offset += len(data)
    f.close() 
conn.close()
```

Comment: Please add some description to what's happening here, as just a block of code is not a good answer.